# IF ( ! $loop->have_posts() ) condition doesn't work - WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

So I'm almost positive I had this working perfectly, then somewhere out of nowhere it seemed not to. I've tinkered around and have had it hide everything and then hide nothing at all. Wondering if anyone spots something I'm doing wrong?

The code below should basically scan all of my products - **simple & variable** - to see whether any **IN STOCK** products have **sale** prices on them. If there are no **IN STOCK** products with **sale** prices, hide a certain CSS ID. Otherwise, do nothing. Not sure what I'm missing...

```
// -----------------------------------------
// HIDE WEEKLY SPECIALS IF THERE ARE NO PRODUCTS

function weeklyspecials() {
    $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array( // Simple products type
                            'key'           => '_sale_price',
                            'value'         => 0,
                            'compare'       => '>',
                            'type'          => 'numeric'
                        ),
                        array( // Variable products type
                            'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                            'value'         => 0,
                            'compare'       => '>',
                            'type'          => 'numeric'
                        )
                    ),
                    array( // Stock status
                        'key' => '_stock_status',
                        'value' => 'instock'
                    )
                )
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<style>#weeklyspecials {display:none;}</style>';
        }
}
add_action ( 'wp_body_open', 'weeklyspecials' );
```

**Results of my `VAR_DUMP()`**

```
object(WP_Query)[18711]
  public 'query' => 
    array (size=3)
      'post_type' => string 'product' (length=7)
      'posts_per_page' => int 4
      'meta_query' => 
        array (size=3)
          'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
  public 'query_vars' => 
    array (size=65)
      'post_type' => string 'product' (length=7)
      'posts_per_page' => int 4
      'meta_query' => 
        array (size=3)
          'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'error' => string '' (length=0)
      'm' => string '' (length=0)
      'p' => int 0
      'post_parent' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment_id' => int 0
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'pagename' => string '' (length=0)
      'page_id' => int 0
      'second' => string '' (length=0)
      'minute' => string '' (length=0)
      'hour' => string '' (length=0)
      'day' => int 0
      'monthnum' => int 0
      'year' => int 0
      'w' => int 0
      'category_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag' => string '' (length=0)
      'cat' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'author' => string '' (length=0)
      'author_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'feed' => string '' (length=0)
      'tb' => string '' (length=0)
      'paged' => int 0
      'meta_key' => string '' (length=0)
      'meta_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'preview' => string '' (length=0)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
      'sentence' => string '' (length=0)
      'title' => string '' (length=0)
      'fields' => string '' (length=0)
      'menu_order' => string '' (length=0)
      'embed' => string '' (length=0)
      'category__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_name__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'facetwp' => boolean true
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => boolean false
      'suppress_filters' => boolean false
      'cache_results' => boolean true
      'update_post_term_cache' => boolean true
      'lazy_load_term_meta' => boolean true
      'update_post_meta_cache' => boolean true
      'nopaging' => boolean false
      'comments_per_page' => string '50' (length=2)
      'no_found_rows' => boolean false
      'order' => string 'DESC' (length=4)
  public 'tax_query' => 
    object(WP_Tax_Query)[18708]
      public 'queries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
      protected 'table_aliases' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'queried_terms' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'primary_table' => string 'wp_posts' (length=8)
      public 'primary_id_column' => string 'ID' (length=2)
  public 'meta_query' => 
    object(WP_Meta_Query)[18709]
      public 'queries' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
      public 'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
      public 'meta_table' => string 'wp_postmeta' (length=11)
      public 'meta_id_column' => string 'post_id' (length=7)
      public 'primary_table' => string 'wp_posts' (length=8)
      public 'primary_id_column' => string 'ID' (length=2)
      protected 'table_aliases' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'wp_postmeta' (length=11)
          1 => string 'mt1' (length=3)
      protected 'clauses' => 
        array (size=3)
          'wp_postmeta' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
          'wp_postmeta-1' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
          'mt1' => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
      protected 'has_or_relation' => boolean true
  public 'date_query' => boolean false
  public 'request' => string 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_sale_price' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_min_variation_sale_price' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) > '0' )
  ) 
  AND 
  ( mt1.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND mt1.meta_value = 'instock' )
) AND wp_posts.'... (length=735)
  public 'posts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'post_count' => int 0
  public 'current_post' => int -1
  public 'in_the_loop' => boolean false
  public 'comment_count' => int 0
  public 'current_comment' => int -1
  public 'found_posts' => int 0
  public 'max_num_pages' => int 0
  public 'max_num_comment_pages' => int 0
  public 'is_single' => boolean false
  public 'is_preview' => boolean false
  public 'is_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_archive' => boolean true
  public 'is_date' => boolean false
  public 'is_year' => boolean false
  public 'is_month' => boolean false
  public 'is_day' => boolean false
  public 'is_time' => boolean false
  public 'is_author' => boolean false
  public 'is_category' => boolean false
  public 'is_tag' => boolean false
  public 'is_tax' => boolean false
  public 'is_search' => boolean false
  public 'is_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_comment_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_trackback' => boolean false
  public 'is_home' => boolean false
  public 'is_privacy_policy' => boolean false
  public 'is_404' => boolean false
  public 'is_embed' => boolean false
  public 'is_paged' => boolean false
  public 'is_admin' => boolean false
  public 'is_attachment' => boolean false
  public 'is_singular' => boolean false
  public 'is_robots' => boolean false
  public 'is_favicon' => boolean false
  public 'is_posts_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_post_type_archive' => boolean true
  private 'query_vars_hash' => string '1f83b003e69dc81d9f9a9bf0531defa3' (length=32)
  private 'query_vars_changed' => boolean true
  public 'thumbnails_cached' => boolean false
  private 'stopwords' => null
  private 'compat_fields' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'query_vars_hash' (length=15)
      1 => string 'query_vars_changed' (length=18)
  private 'compat_methods' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'init_query_flags' (length=16)
      1 => string 'parse_tax_query' (length=15)
```

Comment: did you var_dump the `$loop` to see what is inside or output expected result? This could make sure the query return what you are looking for first.

Comment: Yup. I will add that to my question now. I'm not really sure what to make of it though - as I'm a newbie and usually my var_dumps are for true or false, or integers and the like.

Comment: There is no posts found in your query. I suggest you reduce your query arguments to less conditions and start from simple one like only post_type and post_per_page first. Because it could be your condition not working. If you are familiar with `phpmyadmin` you could use the SQL in the var_dump result to put and see if there is any result. If the result in phpmyadmin is empty then your query is going wrong somewhere.

Comment: I think you are right, but why? It must have something to do with the variable products - because that is where the sale is. For some reason it isn't recognizing that.

Comment: Form your comment in my answer, you get zero posts but you should get at least 1, right? Could you add more details to the question about what you expect and what you get? You just said "it doesn't work as I expected" but you didn't explain what you expect to get and what actually get. That could make us able to help you better. I thought that your problem is that you correctly get zero posts but `have_posts()` evaluate to `true` instead to `false`, but it seems I didn't get you. Please, explain further your problem.

Comment: Apologies. I am trying to loop through the products and use the result to output the ``<style>`` code.

If there are no products found that meet the criteria my query is looking for, do nothing.

If a product does meet that criteria, output the script.

The criteria being : scan all products, and if any of those products have a sale price and are in-stock, they should show up in $loop. Doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: @CollieBuddz maybe you give us some more information about how you create the product. Are you using Woocommerce? Are you doing some custom code for variations? How you do that? Did you refer to Woocommerce's sample or source code for query product with variations? And so on, if you could provide more background information, more could we help.

Comment: Woocommerce variation products. I haven't done anything custom in terms of the variations. My query is based off of some knowledge and also browsing the web for similar situations. Not really sure what else I can add?

Comment: Product variations are stored in a different post type, as far as I can remember. Answer updated, could you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Products variations are a stored as a different post type, `product_variation`, so you have to add that post type to the query:

```
'post_type' => array( 'product', 'product_variation' )
```

Also, you could try to use WooCommerce specific functions, like `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()`, `wc_get_products()` and so on, they could make your life easier when coding for WooCommerce.

Comment: Appreciate the different approach, but still nothing. Must be in the array, because there should be 1 post showing - strange! Why is the wp_reset_postdata() so important?

Comment: That did it! (The different post_type was the issue). Ahhh woocommerce can be frustrating at times. Thanks to everyone that assisted me with this one!